# Underline color is different to link color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using bootstrap and SASS and am getting this weird problem. I set the link colour for all h1-6 elements to #333 and the same for hover.

Other links on my site are styled with a red colour which is stored in the variable `$primary-color`.

With my links the #333 colour is working for heading links but it appears to be inheriting the red colour for the underline. Here is an image and the SASS code below.

[image: Link Underline colour different to link colour]

```
 a {
    color:$primary-color;
    &:hover {
        color:darken($primary-color, 10%);
    }
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h4,h5,h6 {
        color: #333;
        &:hover {
            color: #333 !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, `h1:hover` is `#333`, but `h1:hover a:hover` is `red`. The result is red.

You need to declare `a` in hx, so:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #333;
    &:hover a { /* if links has to be shadow in non=hover state too, there could be only "a" without previous "&:hover " */
        color: #333; /* no important is needed */
    }
}
```